# How to construct the action on chains of the Bockstein homomorphism for homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups, group-extensions, poincare-duality

Given a manifold $X$ and short exact sequence of abelian groups
$$
1\rightarrow A_1\overset{\iota}{\rightarrow} A_2\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} A_3\rightarrow 1
$$
we get the Bockstein map in cohomology $\beta : H^p(X,A_3)\rightarrow H^{p+1}(X,A_1)$. If $X$ is orientable, by using Poincarè duality for homology/cohomology with coefficients in $A_1$ and $A_3$ we induce the Bockstein map in homology $b: H_p(X,A_3)\rightarrow H_{p-1}(X,A_1)$. It is not clear to me how to define it explicitely on chains.

I was expacting something very similar to the cohomology case, but I think there is some difference because regarding cohains the abelian groups appear as value of the maps, while about chains they appear as coefficients. Let me explain better. Given $f\in Z^p(X,A_3)$, this is a map valued in $A_3$, then choosing a section $s:A_3\rightarrow A_2$, $\pi \circ s=id_{A_3}$ we can construct $s(\delta f), \delta s(f)\in C^{p+1}(X,A_2)$ but they are not equal. However since
$$
\pi\left(\delta s(f)-s(\delta f)\right)=0
$$
there exist a cochain $\beta(f)\in C^{p+1}(X,A_1)$ such that
$$
\delta s(f)-s(\delta f)=\iota (\beta(f))
$$
This is the well known algebraic construction of the Bockstein map on cochains, and it really uses the fact that cochains are valued in groups. How one can imitate this on chains?

Comment: Why are you using Poincaré duality and what not to construct bocksteins in homology and not the very same procedure that gives them in cohomology?

Comment: When you tensor the singular complex of your space with the abelian groups A_i you obtain (because the singular groups are free) a short exact sequence of compl exes, and the bocksteins you want are just the corresponding connecting morphisms.

Comment: This is precisely my question: I don't see a clean way to "compose" a chain with the section $s$, since in homology the groups appear as coefficients. In cohomology this is very clear since the abelian groups are the values of the cohains and I can compose with the section.

Comment: If you have a map f:A\to B of abelian groups, and a chain with coefficients in A then just apply f to the coefficients: you end up with a chain with coefficients in B.

Comment: Your question is not so much about Bopcksteins but how exactly $H_*(X,A)$ is a functor of the abelian group A.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly if $c\in C_p(X,A_3)$, $b(c)\in C_{p-1}(X,A_1)$ is defined such that $\iota(b(c))=\partial s(c)-s(\partial c)$, where the action of the maps $\iota$ and $s$ on chains are defined to act on the coefficiens. Is this right?

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: (Add an answer with the details)

Comment: Thank you, I posted a separed question about proving that this is what you get from Poincarè duality